# Sql server string comparison problem with chinese white-space

Tags: sql-server-2008, whitespace

I have a record in my sql server database with the following value for a nvarchar column:
'穂 坂'
The second character is the Unicode value 0x20 which is a simple space character.

There is a unique key constraint on that column.

I get a unique key violation when I try to insert the following value:
'穂　坂'
In this string, the second character is the Unicode value 0x3000, which is a chinese space character.

Why do I get the unique key violation? Why does sql server "convert" the chinese white-space character to a simple space?

Thanks in advance for any insights!
My collation is SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS by the way.

Answer (score 1):

First you may use the approriate string type in SQL including the collation.
Second you may use UNICODE strings beginning by N prefix.

Example:

```
SELECT CAST(N'穂 坂' COLLATE Chinese_Simplified_Pinyin_100_BIN2 AS VARBINARY(32))
```

=> 0x427A20004257

```
SELECT CAST(N'穂　坂' COLLATE Chinese_Simplified_Pinyin_100_BIN2 AS VARBINARY(32))
```

=> 0x427A00304257

Answer (score 0):

It could be that your collation is [width-insensitive](http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/foreign-punctuation.aspx).

Consider:

- changing your database's collation to one that fits your needs, and it width-sensitive.
- change the collation on that particular column to one that is width-sensitive. This could/will lead to more [COLLATE clauses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) throughout your stored procs, etc. Not sure if this is a recommended practice by DBAs.

[image]

Comment: I tried converting to a width-sensitive collation(Latin1_General_CI_AS_WS), but the insert still does causes unique key violation.